# JUnit 5 Extension with Spring @Import and @ImportAutoConfiguration

Tags: java, junit5

I watch this presentation about replacing inheritance by Extension
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=V6_rIa30YzE

To test my Spring Mvc Controller we are doing initialisations in an parent abstract class:

```java
@Import({ControllerMappingConfiguration.class, Translator.class})
@ImportAutoConfiguration(MessageSourceAutoConfiguration.class)
public abstract class AbstractControllerTest {
    @Autowired
    ObjectMapper objectMapper;
    @Autowired
    MockMvc mockMvc;
```

It registers our ModelMapper converters and configures the localisation.

We are using it with inheritance:

```java
@WebMvcTest(controllers = {BankExposureController.class})
class BankExposureControllerTest extends AbstractControllerTest {
```

And it works fine.

I try to replace this approach with an extension and I can't find a way to have the `@Import` and `@ImportAutoConfiguration`working with Extension.

Do you know ho to do it ?

In this example, if it works, I will improve it by using `@ImportAutoConfiguration` for the fields `objectMapper` and `mockMvc`.
I try an extension like:

```java
@Import({ControllerMappingConfiguration.class, Translator.class})
@ImportAutoConfiguration(MessageSourceAutoConfiguration.class)
class AbstractControllerExtension implements Extension {
```